# Query to group by maximum depth of PostgreSQL Ltree?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, group-by, ltree

I want to query for all products with the name "Shania Twain", but I want group them only by the tree with the deepest [nlevel](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ltree.html).

Assuming I have a table like the following with the name `categories`

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|id             |name           |tree           |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|1              |"Music"        |100            |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|2              |"Shania Twain" |100.1          |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|3              |"Artists"      |200            |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|5              |"Country"      |200.2          |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|6              |"Shania Twain" |200.2.4        |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

So, for example,

```
SELECT MAX(cat.id),
       cat.name,
       MAX(cat.tree)
  FROM
       public.categories cat
 WHERE
       cat.name = "Shania Twain"
GROUP BY
       name
HAVING
       MAX(nlevel(cat.tree))
```

The problem lies with the `HAVING` clause requiring a boolean expression. The clause `MAX(nlevel(cat.tree))` will return an integer.

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance

Mahmoud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    cat.id
    cat.name,
    cat.tree
FROM
    public.categories AS cat
WHERE
    cat.name = 'Shania Twain'
AND
   NLEVEL(cat.tree) = (SELECT MAX(NLEVEL(tree) FROM public.categories WHERE cat.name='Shania Twain'))
```

Comment: I will accept this answer because it answers my question, but I wanted to see how I would do it for all entries that have the deepest nlevel.